# Why does assigning a reference to a variable make me not able to return it

Tags: rust

In this code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = {
        &mut vec![1]
    };
    let b = {
        let temp = &mut vec![1];
        temp
    };
    println!("{a:?} {b:?}");
}
```

Why is `a` valid and `b` not valid (*"temporary value dropped while borrowed [E0716]"*)?

It would make sense to me if they were both problematic, why isn't the vec in `a` getting dropped?

Is this simply that the compiler can understand the first example but the second one is to hard for it to understand?

Comment: Maybe Rust is capable of removing the braces if it's just that single statement? `let a = &mut vec![1]` is a valid statement in Rust, and the vec itself is automatically kept alive in the background during the entire scope. But good question, didn't know this would compile; intuitively I would have said it doesn't. For `b` there is no chance that it would work, because `temp` (and with that, the vector) is definitely dropped at the end of the scope.

Comment: @Finomnis Good point, it makes sense although it's a bit strange that it disregards the scope I made

Comment: @PeterHall Note 100% true, though: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=95c2e4371ee4558fcdef6901f307aa9e I feel like it behaves rather as if the return value expression isn't part of the inner, but the outer scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one sentence: `a` is a temporary while `b` is not.

`temp` is a variable; [variables are always dropped at the end of the enclosing scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#scopes-of-local-variables). The scope ends before we assign it to `b`.

In contrast, the `vec![]` in `a` is a temporary, as it is not assigned to a variable. [Temporaries are generally dropped at the end of the statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes), however because the statement is a `let` declaration, the temporary inside it is subject to [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension) and its lifetime is extended to match the lifetime of `a` itself, that is, until the enclosing block **of `a`**.

Note that to be precise, `temp` is also assigned a temporary that is subject to temporary lifetime extension - but its extended lifetime matches the lifetime **of `temp`**, as it is part of its declaration.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of `Temporary lifetime extension`

Comment: @AharonSambol Note that if you come from C/C++, that's one of the more subtle differences. Directly assigning a reference to a temporary is allowed in Rust, but not in C. It has nothing to do with which language is more capable, it's simply a language design decision.

Comment: @Finomnis C++ does indeed have temporary lifetime extension, I believe only when binding to a `const` reference. `std::string const &a = std::string("foo");` is valid IIRC. (C does not have references at all, so there is no point in comparing to C.)